# How to keep divs at equal distances in columns?

Tags: html, css

How to keep the divs at equal distances from each other like they have space around themselves but in a column manner.

like

```
div 1

div 2

div 3
```

one below the other

Comment: Share the html and css that you tried

Comment: explain what you are going to do more detail and share more detail information.

Answer (score 2):

We could put them in a div container then using flex as below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```